# web-app can't establish any connection to a 64-bit database configured with windows odbc data source administrator

Tags: tomcat, java-8, odbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

Our legacy software based on Java8/JEE and a Sybase Database.

The web-app is deployed to a Apache Tomcat 8 32-bit server. The 32-bit DB connection was configured with the windows odbc data source administrator. Everything was good so far.

Now... we need to connect to a new 64-bit based Sybase Database. So i did setup a new 64-bit DB connection with the windows odbc data source administrator. 
The connection test in administrator tool works fine.
I also did changed the db-connection-properties to the new 64-bit db connection in our web-app.

But our web-app can't establish any db-connection to the new configured (64-bit) odbc data source.

Any ideas why ? 
Thank you

Comment: 32-bit applications cannot use 64-bit drivers or DSNs on Windows.

Comment: @GordThompson what do we need to do to get this work again ? Build the application as 64-bit, deploy it to an Tomcat and let it run on a 64-bit JVM ? Regards

Comment: Please post the error message. Also, try to use the 32-bit ODBC with your app, not the 64-bit. It's possible it can't even see it. The location of your ODBC admin tool should be at %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: @access_granted Thx. I will update my post when i have the error msg. I will give them a try to connect to my 64-bit db over 32-bit ODBC using ODBC admin tool located at %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe